# How to add a custom field and incrementing value for all the published posts

Tags: wp-query, mysql

I'm trying to add a custom field value "article"  and auto - increment value starting from 1 for all the published and new post  starting from the first post.

I'm trying with the below code in Mysql. but its not working

```
insert into wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
select ID 'article', 'AUTO_INCREMENT=VALUES' from wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post';
```

Comment: Can you provide some context as to what you're trying to achieve by doing this? Is it just a list of posts in chronological order with a number next to them indicating this is the first, this is the second etc?

Comment: i need to generate no of post available on my wordpress site , i'd  have done this with post id but it is not sequential. thats why m planning to add custom field  from first post to the latest post ,,,,

Comment: That's a super expensive way of getting a count of how many published posts are on a site, and the solution you posted below will make saving and editing posts very slow, and it'll get slower as you add more posts

Answer (score -1):

It works ... here is the code

```
function updateNumbers() {
/* numbering the published posts: preparation: create an array with the ID in sequence of publication date, /
/ save the number in custom field 'article' of post with ID  /
/ to show in post (within the loop) use <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'article',true); ?>
/ alchymyth 2010 */
global $wpdb;
$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' ";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
$counts = 0 ;
if ($pageposts):
foreach ($pageposts as $post):
setup_postdata($post);
$counts++;
add_post_meta($post->ID, 'article', $counts, true);
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'article', $counts);
endforeach;
endif;
}  

add_action ( 'publish_post', 'updateNumbers' );
add_action ( 'deleted_post', 'updateNumbers' );
add_action ( 'edit_post', 'updateNumbers' );
```

Comment: Those hooks provide post IDs, you don't need the WPDB query, `update_post_meta` is the only call needed